# Personal github account linked to employer. Question about privacy

Tags: github

In order to acces my employers gitub repos, which are part of an organization in github, I linked my personal account to my employers organization account. Now every time I push to my personal repos I get the usual notification in my personal email linked to my account but I also get the same notification to my work email. This raises serious privacy concerns for me because I don't want my employer tracking my personal and private commits.

Is there a way to just notify in my work email when I push to work related repose and only to my personal account when I pushed a personal repos?

A way of handling this would be to decouple my github account from my employer and start one account only for link to my employer but this just seems silly. What are proper ways to deal with these privacy concerns? What are best practices?

Thanks.

Comment: If you want to keep these things completely separate, create separate accounts. Something like `xv70-companyname`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can control the email address that's used for notifications by going to https://github.com/settings/notifications and choosing options under "Custom routing". You'll want to set the default for your account, which is under "Email notification preferences" above, to be only your personal account, and then set your employer's organization to go to your work email.

Note that if you add a personal access token or take other actions that affect account security, you'll be notified at all email addresses for your account, and that can't be disabled.

Comment: I do have a token set up to validate commits etc to the organization repo. This might be the culprit. Is this what you mean when you say that can't be disabled?

Comment: No, I mean that if you add a new token or a new email address to your account (or certain other security sensitive actions), GitHub will email all your addresses so you get notified quickly in case of an account compromise. Simply using a token to push need not notify all your email addresses.